# Core data join table, has many through, fetched properties predicate

Tags: ios, core-data

[image: Xcode Data Model]
How do you write a Fetched Property for the Place Entity that will present an Array of Users?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For a fetched property `users` of *Place* that retrieves all users whose check-in is related to the given place, set

- the destination of the fetched property to "User"
- and the predicate to "ANY checkins.event == $FETCH_SOURCE"

[image]

Now you can get the array of users for a place:

```
Place *place = ...;
NSArray *users = [place valueForKey:@"users"];
```

This fetched property corresponds to the following fetch request:

```
Place *place = ...;
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"User"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY checkins.event == %@", place];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSArray *users = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

If you declare the fetched property `users` as a dynamic property:

```
@interface Place (FetchedProperties)
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray *users;
@end

@implementation Place (FetchedProperties)
@dynamic users;
@end
```

then you can retrieve the value using property syntax:

```
NSArray *users = place.users;
// instead of: NSArray *users = [place valueForKey:@"users"];
```

***But note*** that you can get the same result (as a set) directly, without using a fetched property:

```
Place *place = ...;
NSSet *users = [place.checkins valueForKey:@"user"];
```

Comment: If I want to sort the user based on the created_at property of Checkin, how to set a sort descriptor key?

Comment: @Subhash: I don't think that you can add a sort descriptor to a fetched property, you have to sort the users array after fetching it. - Or you use a normal fetch request where you can add a sort descriptor.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a similar model as mentioned above and using fetch controller to fetch the data. When I set the sort key as created_at, i get an error as "Exception = to-many key not allowed here". Is this a limitation with Fetch controller? Above mentioned solution by you(without using fetch controller) is the only way to solve this problem?

Comment: @Subhash: It is perhaps better if you post your own question, describe the entities and relationships and show your code and the error message. That makes it easier to help with your concrete problem.

Comment: I have posted a separate question. Thanks for your help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760425/issue-with-setting-nssortdescriptor-key-in-nsfetchresultcontroller

Answer (score 2):

I hope I did understand you correctly. You want a list of users that have checked in at a certain place?

Then you do it the other way around. You fetch all `User`s that have at least one `Checkin` with a certain `Place`.

In Core-Data terms you'll need a subquery for this.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"User"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(checkins, $CHECKIN, $CHECKIN.event == %@).@count > 0", place];
request.predicate = predicate;
/* and so on */
```

There is not much documentation about SUBQUERY. A little bit is written in the discussion of [`expressionForSubquery:usingIteratorVariable:predicate:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001190-SW22).

And the fetched property would be in the Place entity with a destination entity User and the predicate `SUBQUERY(checkins, $CHECKIN, $CHECKIN.event == $FETCH_SOURCE).@count > 0`