# How to refer to fetched property's owner property?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Simply, I have two Entities: `Goal` and `Service`:

`Service` has `returnVisits` property and `Goal` has `hours` property.

Now for the fetched property I need to create a predicate like this:

```
`SELF.returnVisits = hours`
```

like you can see on the image below. This is `Goal` entity:

[image]

The question is:

**How to compare the value of destination entity to hours from owner entity? Is there a way to do this?**

Comment: It is long ago that I tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14412750/1187415, something like `"hours == $FETCH_SOURCE.returnVisits"` might work.

Comment: `'[<_NSCoreDataTaggedObjectID 0xd000000000180000> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key returnVisits.'`, shouldn't it be reversed?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Comment: `$FETCH_SOURCE.hours = SELF.returnVisits` ALSO doesnt work with error: `'[<_NSCoreDataTaggedObjectID 0xd000000000200000> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key hours.'`

Comment: `$FETCH_SOURCE gets replaced by a reference to the entity that owns the fetched property. By using this variable we can reference properties in the owning entity.` - from docs, it should work, but does not.